# Service Bus queue token issue

Tags: azure, acs, azureservicebus

I am getting this error when i am giving the key for creating the queue

> System.UnauthorizedAccessException was unhandled   Message=The token
>   provider was unable to provide a security token while accessing
>   'https://sharan-sb.accesscontrol.windows.net/WRAPv0.9/'. Token
>   provider returned message: 'Error:Code:401:SubCode:T0:Detail:ACS50009:
>   SWT token is
>   invalid.:TraceID:afb424d9-d69c-4460-90d4-23ddd49ad950:TimeStamp:2013-07-23
>   16:08:29Z'.   Source=Microsoft.ServiceBus   StackTrace:
>       Server stack trace: 
>          at Microsoft.ServiceBus.TokenProviderUtility.GetMessagingWebToken(ITokenProvider
>   tokenProvider, String appliesTo, String action, Boolean bypassCache,
>   TimeSpan timeout)
>          at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.HttpWebRequestExtensions.AddAuthorizationHeader(HttpWebRequest
>   request, ITokenProvider tokenProvider, String action)
>          at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.ServiceBusResourceOperations.CreateAsyncResult`1.<GetAsyncSteps>d__2.MoveNext()
>          at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.IteratorAsyncResult`1.MoveNextStep()
>          at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.IteratorAsyncResult`1.EnumerateSteps(CurrentThreadType
>   state)
>          at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.IteratorAsyncResult`1.Start()
>       Exception rethrown at [0]: 
>          at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Common.AsyncResult.End[TAsyncResult](IAsyncResult
>   result)
>          at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.IteratorAsyncResult`1.End(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult)
>          at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.ServiceBusResourceOperations.EndCreate[T](IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult)
>          at Microsoft.ServiceBus.NamespaceManager.CreateQueueAsyncResult.CreateDescription(CreateQueueAsyncResult
>   thisPtr, IAsyncResult r)
>          at Microsoft.ServiceBus.NamespaceManager.CreateQueueAsyncResult.<GetAsyncSteps>b__a(CreateQueueAsyncResult
>   thisPtr, IAsyncResult r)
>          at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.IteratorAsyncResult`1.EnumerateSteps(CurrentThreadType
>   state)
>       Exception rethrown at [1]: 
>          at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Common.AsyncResult.End[TAsyncResult](IAsyncResult
>   result)
>          at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.IteratorAsyncResult`1.End(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult)
>          at Microsoft.ServiceBus.NamespaceManager.OnEndCreateQueue(IAsyncResult
>   result)
>          at Microsoft.ServiceBus.NamespaceManager.EndCreateQueue(IAsyncResult
>   result)
>          at Microsoft.ServiceBus.NamespaceManager.CreateQueue(QueueDescription
>   description)
>          at BasicQueueDemo.Program.Main(String[] args) in D:\Azure\PluralSight\Azure Videos\9-Windows Azure Service
>   Bus\materials\demos\after\BasicQueueDemo\BasicQueueDemo\Program.cs:line
>   20
>          at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
>          at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
>          at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
>          at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
>          at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean
>   ignoreSyncCtx)
>          at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
>          at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()   InnerException: System.IdentityModel.Tokens.SecurityTokenException
>          Message=The token provider was unable to provide a security token while accessing
>   'https://sharan-sb.accesscontrol.windows.net/WRAPv0.9/'. Token
>   provider returned message: 'Error:Code:401:SubCode:T0:Detail:ACS50009:
>   SWT token is
>   invalid.:TraceID:afb424d9-d69c-4460-90d4-23ddd49ad950:TimeStamp:2013-07-23
>   16:08:29Z'.
>          Source=Microsoft.ServiceBus
>          StackTrace:
>               at Microsoft.ServiceBus.TokenProviderHelper.ThrowException(Uri
>   requestUri, WebException exception)
>               at Microsoft.ServiceBus.TokenProviderHelper.GetAccessTokenCore(Uri
>   requestUri, String appliesTo, String requestToken, String
>   simpleAuthAssertionFormat, TimeSpan timeout, String& expiresIn)
>               at Microsoft.ServiceBus.TokenProviderHelper.GetHttpAuthAccessTokenByAssertion(Uri
>   requestUri, String appliesTo, String requestToken, String
>   simpleAuthAssertionFormat, TimeSpan timeout)
>               at Microsoft.ServiceBus.SharedSecretTokenProvider.OnBeginGetWebToken(String
>   appliesTo, String action, TimeSpan timeout, AsyncCallback callback,
>   Object state)
>               at Microsoft.ServiceBus.TokenProvider.GetWebTokenAsyncResult..ctor(TokenProvider
>   tokenProvider, String appliesTo, String action, Boolean bypassCache,
>   TimeSpan timeout, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
>               at Microsoft.ServiceBus.TokenProvider.BeginGetWebToken(String appliesTo,
>   String action, Boolean bypassCache, TimeSpan timeout, AsyncCallback
>   callback, Object state)
>               at Microsoft.ServiceBus.TokenProviderUtility.GetMessagingWebToken(ITokenProvider
>   tokenProvider, String appliesTo, String action, Boolean bypassCache,
>   TimeSpan timeout)
>          InnerException: System.Net.WebException
>               Message=The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.
>               Source=System
>               StackTrace:
>                    at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
>                    at Microsoft.ServiceBus.TokenProviderHelper.GetAccessTokenCore(Uri
>   requestUri, String appliesTo, String requestToken, String
>   simpleAuthAssertionFormat, TimeSpan timeout, String& expiresIn)
>               InnerException:

Comment: This essentially means that your IssuerName / IssuerKey is not able to get a valid token. Can you share the code you have or the connection string details / steps that you are using?

Comment: const string queueName = "thequeue";
            var tokenProvider = TokenProvider.CreateSharedSecretTokenProvider("ManageName",
                "Metioned Key here ");
  var uri = ServiceBusEnvironment.CreateServiceUri("http", "sharantr", string.Empty);
            var namespaceManager = new NamespaceManager(uri, tokenProvider);
            var qd = namespaceManager.CreateQueue(new QueueDescription(queueName)

Comment: Can you try to replace the "http" above with "sb"?

Comment: Were you attempting to use an issuer name & key from ACS, or where you wanting to use the Shared Access Signature from the portal?

Comment: This exact exception occurs for me as well. happens every few days or so. A server restart always solves it.